# how can i use multiple addview() to inflate xml multiple times in android

Tags: android

i am getting this error :
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

XML file name is **panchang_cal_inflate**

Here is my code:

```
public class PanchangCal extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_panchang_cal);

    LinearLayout linearday=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.sun2);
    LinearLayout linearday1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.sun20);

    LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_panchang_cal_inflate, null);

    linearday1.addView(myView);

    linearday.addView(myView);

  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to add `myView` as a sub-view to `linearday1` and `linearday`? Because that will not work like this.

If you want to to this, you'd have to inflate the layout twice:

```
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View myView1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_panchang_cal_inflate, null);
View myView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_panchang_cal_inflate, null);

linearday1.addView(myView1);
linearday.addView(myView2);
```

However, I do believe you actually want to add `linearday1` and `linearday` as sub-views of `myView` - am I wrong?

```
myView.addView(linearday1);
myView.addView(linearday);
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to use the code above 30-times, you could use a loop like this:

```
View[] linearday = new View[30];
/** Save your linearday layouts in this array **/

LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    View myView inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_panchang_cal_inflate, null);
    linearday[i].addView(myView);
}
```

and for the second code block it's quite similar:

```
View[] linearday = new View[30];
/** Save your linearday layouts in this array **/

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View myView inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_panchang_cal_inflate, null);
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    myView.addView(linearday[i]);
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
As requested in the comments, you want more details about the array-filling process when your views are stored in an XML file:

There are two ways to accomplish that. If your layouts have completely random ID's in then XML file, then you would have to do it like this:

```
View[] linearday = new View[30];
linearday[0] = findViewById(R.id.linearday_hello);
linearday[1] = findViewById(R.id.linearday_window);
linearday[2] = findViewById(R.id.linearday_test);
// ... and so on
```

However, if they have a common pattern and only an increasing index (e.g. `linearday0`, `linearday1`, `linearday2`), then you can shorten the code like this:

```
View[] linearday = new View[30];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    int resid = getResources().getIdentifier("linearday" + i, "id", getPackageName());
    linearday[i] = findViewById(resid);
}
```

Comment: i am trying to add xml which has relative layout into these two layouts linearday1 and linearday

Comment: thanks it really worked , what if i want to use this for like 30 times ?

Comment: both! the first code block and second too , i have created 30 linear layouts and now i want to insert my xml in 30 linear layouts , should i use View myView1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_panchang_cal_inflate, null);
View myView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_panchang_cal_inflate, null);                                                                 myView.addView(linearday1);
myView.addView(linearday); 30 times ? or array or for loop ?

Comment: /** Save your linearday layouts in this array **/  ?? how can i do it ?

Comment: Well that depends on your code. Are you creating those views dynamically?

Comment: i am getting error when i add linearday[i].addView(myview[i])

Comment: i am not able to use linearday[i].addview(myview[i]) it gives me error but out of for loop its working, the .addview keyword becomes red

Comment: It's `addView`, not `addview`